# What is the purpose of the orcacle cursor(select ..) query in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to understand the purpose of using cursor(select..) queries. 
For example, I got this from the oracle doc. I can just join employees with departments table. What's the deal with the cursor?

```
SELECT department_name, CURSOR(SELECT salary, commission_pct 
   FROM employees e
   WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id)
   FROM departments d
   ORDER BY department_name;
```

Comment: This query fetches the department name, and a cursor reference to the salary and comm percentage of all the employees in that department. Join gives you multiple rows in department table, matching the corresponding employee count. And there is an interesting discussion [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:7866466844558)

Comment: We have to fetch query in limited sets. If made in bigger batch, we MAX out the possible opened cursors. When opened in sets of 50, 50 cursors are opened and closed after the fetch.! Major difference from a normal query is, we can;t return multiple columns/rows in a normal query (scalar), which is possible by CURSOR expressions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CURSOR expressions are a seldom-used feature that enable you to pass sets of data to a PL/SQL procedure.

This allows advanced functionality such as chaining parallel pipelined functions.  That provides a way to quickly process multiple stages of procedural code.  See the [PL/SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#LNPLS918) for an example.

It is an interesting feature but using CURSOR expressions is often a huge mistake.  It means that most of your processing will be done in PL/SQL instead of SQL.  PL/SQL is great for controlling SQL but it is generally not where you want to do the heavy lifting.

I've only seen CURSOR expressions used for two reasons:

1. Developers were unaware of intermediate or advanced SQL features, such as analytic functions, MODEL, etc.
2. Building an enterprise rules engine.